# How to specify path to build a package for azure-pipelines.yml in a Mono-Repo?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, pipeline, monorepo

I have a monorepo with a folder structure like this:

- root
- ->packageA
- ->packageB
- ->packageC

How can I alter the azure-pipelines.yml to build packageA

I have tried altering the azure-pipelines.yml by specifying the path to packageA. However, I am a newbie to ci/cd so I am not sure how to solve my problem. Currently I have this as my azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run unit_tests
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

The .yml file is in the root folder of the monorepo. The pipeline build will fail because it cannot find the package.json to run the npm commands in packageA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to use a bash script under the script task. For example the workaround looks something like this:

```
- script: | 
    cd server && npm run install
    npm run install mocha-junit-reporter
    npm run unit_tests 
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Answer (score 7):

`script` is a shortcut to the [Command Line Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

You are able to specify a working directory in which your scripts will run

```
- script: # script path or inline
  workingDirectory: #
  displayName: #
  failOnStderr: #
  env: { string: string } # mapping of environment variables to add
```

In my experience specifying more than one script to run in a different directory fails, my fix is to use two script tasks such as:

```
- script: npm install
  workingDirectory: client
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: npm run build
  workingDirectory: client
  displayName: 'npm run build'
```

This is the code from my own pipelines